# Mobile Application Development - How it should be organised

Tags: mobile, architecture, sequence, development-environment

I'm comming today because I never had, as student, any courses about how should I organise the sequences of a mobile application. Same on internet, I can't find anything really interesting about it. So I'm opening this question!

---

**First Page**

When I use launch an application, how does it works in background?

**->** Does the app starts on  the `LoginPage()` and try to connect to the `API/SERVER`? Once it's did, the user stays on `LoginPage()` or the app goes on the `MainPage()` then?

**->** Does the app starts on `RedirectionPage()` and try to connect to the `API/SERVER`? Once it's did, the user is either redirected on the `LoginPage()` on the `MainPage()` then?

**->** Does the app starts on `MainPage()` and try to connect to the `API/SERVER`? Once it's did, the user stays on `MainPage()` or the app goes on the `LoginPage()` if the user isn't connected then?

*Of course, the idea is to have to user already stored on the phone storage (see below).*

---

**MainPage which contains multiple Page/View/Fragment**

As Android & Xamarin.Forms developer, I know that for Android you have a [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in order to manage multiple views on the same page (i.e. When you have to provide a form to make fill by the User). On Xamarin.Forms, it doesn't exists at the moment *(but Xamarin put it on their white list)* so maybe for some other language, it doesn't exist too.

**->** **So  How to organize it?** I mean, you can have 3 `Views` (3 mainLayout) and make them `Visible/Invisible`. But it means you only have 1 `Controler`  for the 3 `Views`.

**->** I also tought that **Maybe**, we could load in background each pages to *avoid* the load at the `Navigation` time? But it would be to much of information in the dynamic memory no?

---

**Deal with TCP/IP Connection**

Today,  it's not that hard to create a socket to connect itself to a `TCP/UDP` server, but how can you handle the different disconnection?

**-> Socket Errors.** When you got a problem such as the server which stops, the internet connection of the device which is stops or which got problem to get signals etc. **How does you deal with it?**. I mean by that, do you make a pop-up to alert the user or do you make an infinite `while(true)` to try to reconnect yourself?

**->** Let say that now, the device cannot connect itself to the server due to internet signal problem, the device would never be able to connect to the server then. **Can you tell it to the User or the app will just continue to trying to connect without timeout?**

---

**Stored Data**

Lot of app today has data saved on the phone storage, but about it, does a security has to be create for some of those files?

**-> User:** In my way, I store the user name/password on the phone storage to escape a reconnection all of the time when the app starts. But, these data are personal so, **Does they has to be encrypted?**

**-> Preferences/Settings and Stored Cache:** I think for them, a simple file write in something such as XML can be store directly  whithout any encryption. But, to escape to each time, load data, angain and again, **Does it's better to store a part of them directly on the phone?**.  If this solution is cheaper about the data exchanges with internet, then **How to organize their proper save?**. In much, the size of these files can begin really important and then, a storage on the external storage could be better, isn't? But if the user hasn't something as a `SD CARD`, then is it possible to change programmaticaly, the path for the save to the Internal Storage?

**-> Framework/Language options:** I know in `Android`, the **[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)** can be used in order to save some `Values` by using `Keys`. In `Xamarin Forms`, something similar exists  with **[Properties Dictonary](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary)**. But two questions comes in my mind: **Does the data access is possible from another app?** and **Does the data are encrypted?**. Also, **the using of these functions, is it optimized to store thousand value by example? If no, so what range of data it's optimized?**

---

I know it's a lot of questions, maybe stupid, maybe they are really common I don't know, but these questions are some point I never really understand carefully and today, I would like an explanation.

A simple answer could  be: *Read the Application Development Manual* but it's a big reading which just confuse myself more than how I am today.

**Thank you for this reading, either if you just read or answer.** I also hope, these question will be very helpful for people who are in the same confusion as I am :)

Comment: You are confusing software development with engineering. Engineering has rules and the rules are followed. Software development essentially has no rules, it is in general a free-for-all, what ever the developer personally likes.The exceptions are financial and life treating software such as aircraft, medical, etc. One dev thinks 6,000 lines in a method is fine, another 6 and generally each goes their own way. Bugs are expected (except in code written by others ) and even security generally does not follow best practices. In general software developers are not professionals.

Comment: You're right for some part, thank for this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Questions, and zaph's comment is interesting too!

I would say that there is one key component of mobile development that you are missing related to some of your questions.  That is, the fact that your application will utilize more than just the main thread (UI thread).

For example, when you have a startup page and ask how it should be structured, you want to be utilizing *async and await*.  After your page is shown (in XamarinForms you may want to use the constructor or onAppearing depending on your specific situation), you will want to have your actual task of logging in running off of the UI thread.  A fair amount of your time in Xamarin will be spent making intelligent decisions about async, await, and the UI thread to give your users the best experience possible while keeping your code maintainable and unit-test friendly.

Since your post comes off as both serious and sounds like enterprise development, when talking about local storage, you need to look into SQLCipher which will provide you with the encryption at rest that you are looking for.  This will cost you $500 per developer per targeted OS, however.

Of course, some of your security decisions need to be impacted by how closely you control the user devices and whether you distribute your application through the app store.

While I'm not sure I like zaph's generalization of software developers, you will certainly have to be creative in problem solving and learn from experience as you go, rather than follow a written set of rules.

Comment: I would suggest reading Kent Beck, "Uncle" Bob Martin, the latter has a video series and similar authors. Over 40 years the way writing code, personal preferences, have not changed a lot, the thing that has changed, at least from my history, is the acceptance of bugs. Professionals have standards, certifications and mandatory continuing education, usually 40 hours/year and an a period of supervised experience of around five years. Think your dentist, lawyer, CPA, MD, even my wife. Do you see this in your co-workers? If not they are not professionals. A college degree is an entrance card.

Comment: @Mark Sure we don't need to just follow written rules but we have learned some things and we should not continue repeating learned mistakes. WRT security we have a good idea of what is bad and best practices that are not static but evolving. So why do we have so  many developers making the same mistakes? SQL injection, poor handling of login credentials, hash and encryption algorithms that we found to be broken 10 or more years ago still being used in new work! Developers that for one reason or another are not embracing HTTPS and TLS 1.2. None of this is professional.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for the info & explanation.  I can see your point of view now.  I would only add that frequently even knowledgeable and hard-working developers can face institutional hurdles that prevent them from doing what they know is correct.  This can be as simple as unrealistic timelines or as intractable as an institutional resistance to change.  Sometimes, even following the security standards of the company forces a developer to do something he knows is insecure!  Pity the programmer who, 50 years from now, will have to use HTTPS & TLS 1.2 because of a document being written today.

Comment: There are always options. I was at a company when a ridiculous secret mandate came down, I mention that is was wrong, my manager asked me to close the door and then told me someone might walk past his office as I made my comment criticizing a policy and that was not acceptable. I left the next week and I had a better higher paying job the next week. At another company a VP came up with a BS security protocol that did not work, I rebelled, got in trouble but won and got the company to hire a security expert to review our security projects and ended up friends with the VP. Just Do It.